# Angular Js $injector:unpr error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to angular and I was trying to implement a custom service. Code is below:

app.js

```
angular.module('hrg', [
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngTouch',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'hrg.home'
])

.service('userService', ['', function(){
//data
}])
```

home.js

```
angular.module('hrg.home', ['ui.router'])

.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$http','$cookies','$state','consts', 'userService',
  function($scope, $http, $cookies, $state, consts, userService) {
  //data
}])
```

index.html

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="components/home/home.js"></script>
```

The error is: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=userServiceProvider%20%3C-%20userService%20%3C-%20HomeController

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put a `''` inside `userService` inline DI array, which ask for `''` that is culprit of your issue. Because when you inject `userService` dependency inside controller, angular injector goes for creating an instance of `userService` service.

When resolving dependency from `userService` DI array, it passes `''` to `injector`, then first it creates provider name by concatenate it with `Provider` suffix like `''+ 'Provider` with result to `Provider` as dependency name & obviously there is no such dependency present. So angular is throwing an exception `$injector/unpr?` means `Injector unknown provider`

Change below service code

```
                    //VVVVVVV//unwanted '' blank dependency
.service('userService', ['', function(){
   //data
}])
```

to

```
.service('userService', [function(){ //removed `''` dependency
   //data
}])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue was solved. Got to learn something new. :)

Comment: @tumulr Glad to help you..Thanks :)